# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mcruiseon.common.Globals.RideType

Tags: java, enums, hibernate-mapping

My hbm file entry

```
        <property name="rideType">
            <column name="rideType" />
            <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                <param name="enumClass">com.mcruiseon.common.Globals.RideType</param>
                <param name="type">12</param>               
            </type>
        </property>
```

Exception

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to instantiate custom type: org.hibernate.type.EnumType
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.custom(TypeFactory.java:218)
    ...
    at com.mcruiseon.server.mCruiseOnServer.main(mCruiseOnServer.java:101)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Enum class not found
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.setParameterValues(EnumType.java:239)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.injectParameters(TypeFactory.java:131)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mcruiseon.common.Globals.RideType
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.setParameterValues(EnumType.java:236)
    ... 19 more
```

Code

```
public class Globals {
     ...whole bunch of code...
     public enum RideType {
        PER_KM("PER_KM"), PER_HOUR_1("PER_HOUR_1"), PER_HOUR_2("PER_HOUR_2"), PER_HOUR_4(
                "PER_HOUR_4"), PER_HOUR_8("PER_HOUR_8"), PER_HOUR_10(
                "PER_HOUR_10"), PER_HOUR_12("PER_HOUR_12"), PER_HOUR_16(
                "PER_HOUR_16");
        private String description;

        RideType(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return new String(description);
        }

        public static RideType getRideType(String value) {
            if ("PER_KM".equalsIgnoreCase(value))
                return PER_KM;
            else if ("PER_HOUR_1".equalsIgnoreCase(value))
                return PER_HOUR_1;
            else if ("PER_HOUR_2".equalsIgnoreCase(value))
                return PER_HOUR_2;
            else if ("PER_HOUR_4".equalsIgnoreCase(value))
                return PER_HOUR_4;
            else if ("PER_HOUR_8".equalsIgnoreCase(value))
                return PER_HOUR_8;
            else if ("PER_HOUR_10".equalsIgnoreCase(value))
                return PER_HOUR_10;
            else if ("PER_HOUR_12".equalsIgnoreCase(value))
                return PER_HOUR_12;
            else if ("PER_HOUR_16".equalsIgnoreCase(value))
                return PER_HOUR_16;
            return null;
        }
    };
    ...whole bunch of code...
}
```

I have tried all SO questions and answers, and for some crazy reason it still throws this exception. What am I missing here ?

Comment: is Globals a class??

Comment: yes, globals is a class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like an enum declared within a class (inner class enum). If that's true.

Change:

```
<param name="enumClass">com.mcruiseon.common.Globals.RideType</param>
```

To:

```
<param name="enumClass">com.mcruiseon.common.Globals$RideType</param>
```